# Is it legally possible for a tenant to replace their landlord?

Tags: rental-property, tenancy

I was wondering if a tenant feels their landlord has wronged them, if there could be any legal argument, even an unusual one, that if a person has established a residence somewhere to some non-trivial extent, they have some inherent right or claim to that as their residence or home, and it may be possible to remove the landlord rather than the landlord removing the tenant.

Eviction is really common so in general I think tenants own property like any other situation, for example, a company can fire employees, a hostel can kick out a guest, and so on. Still, are there any interesting examples of this happening? One could be some kind of community outreach / movement or special legal circumstance to allow someone to stay. Another could be some way of having some third party or organization purchase the property from the landlord.

Comment: "...in general I think tenants own property like any other situation..."  Maybe you could help us understand why you believe this, and what you think a landlord is.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it legally possible for a tenant to replace their landlord?

Generally not. The landlord-tenant relationship flows from the landlord's ownership of the property and the tenant can do nothing to change that (short of buying the land from the landlord in a voluntary transaction).

If the landlord were a government agency, the tenant could petition the government to put a different employee in charge of managing the lease, and if the landlord were a trust it is barely conceivable that the tenant could assist some other party in removing the trustee and replacing the trustee with another trustee (particularly if the trust was a charitable trust or the tenant was also a beneficiary of the trust).

But, generally speaking, this is not possible.

Comment: "generally speaking," indeed.  The question contemplates the tenant having been wronged by the landlord.  Could a landlord be dispossessed of a property or at least restrained from participating in the property's management in a particularly egregious case?  I'm thinking of rent-regulated tenants in New York City, who enjoy particularly strong protections.  I know that such tenants are sometimes the target of harassment from landlords; what's the most drastic sanction that can be imposed on a landlord in such a case?

Comment: @phoog I am not aware of any circumstance in which a landlord can be dispossessed of a property for wrongful conduct towards tenants. An injunction is entirely different matter. A large fine and possibly an injunction would be typical penalties.

Comment: I suppose the fine could be so large that the landlord has to sell the property to pay it.  Or has to declare bankruptcy, which might also result in the property changing hands.  But that's only an indirect effect.

Comment: @ohwilleke thanks, that's what I thought.  Indeed, the harassment cases I've heard of largely suggest that for most tenants, the point at which the personal stress becomes unbearable is somewhere before the courts step in -- indeed, in one case I know of, it was before the courts _could_ step in, because the tenant (of a rent-stabilized apartment) decided that even going to court in the first place would be too stressful and just moved out.

Answer (score 0):

Jurisdiction: [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

There is no general right to do this. However, in some specific circumstances it can be possible to do this, or achieve a similar effect.

#### Leasehold enfranchisement

If you live in a flat and are a tenant under a lease (as opposed to a tenancy agreement), and meet various conditions, you can effect a compulsory purchase of your freehold under [Section 1 of the Leasehold Reform, Housing and Urban Development Act 1993](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1993/28/section/1).

As an alternative to removing the landlord altogether, there is the "right to manage" under [Section 71 of the Commonhold and Leasehold Reform Act 2002](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2002/15/section/71).

### Local authority management orders

This applies where your property is either an HMO or a "Part 3 House" as defined in [Section 146 of the Housing Act 2004](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/34/section/146). Without going into too many details, an HMO is a house in multiple occupation or certain blocks of flats which do not meet the requirements of the [Building Regulations 2010](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/34/section/146), and a "Part 3 House" is any property which falls within a zone that the local authority has designated as a "selective licensing zone" (a zone in which landlords are required to have a licence before they can rent their property).

In such properties, the local authority can make an "interim management order" (applicable for no longer than 12 months) or a "final management order" (no longer than 5  years) which enables them to "[secure] the proper management of the house" - effectively permitting the council to take over management from the landlord.

There is both a duty and a right to make such orders and different conditions attach to each. The conditions which must be met for an interim management order are set out in [Section 102](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/34/section/102) and for a final management order in [Section 113](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/34/section/113). Broadly, these conditions relate the health and safety of the property and whether or not an HMO or Part 3 licence is capable of being issued.

Local authorities will generally use other measures available to them before considering management orders as a last resort.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, it is legal to simply purchase the property you are renting from the current landlord, then sell it to a new landlord with the stipulation that they renew your old lease.

Comment: In some cases it won't be necessary to stipulate a lease renewal as the tenant will have a statutory right to the renewal that survives the change of ownership.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. Obviously the landlord and tenant can *agree* to do this, but the question is asking if it can be done without the landlord's agreement.

Comment: @JBentley, It’s admittedly a silly answer to a silly question done on purpose to make a point. (See my comment to the OP). It does, however, provide an answer to the question as it was asked even if you don’t like it. Yes, there are other legal options in a dispute, (that I don’t address) and asking about them is fair, but there appears to be a deep misunderstanding of the fundamental concept of “ownership” at the root of the question.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a completely silly question in that there are actually some scenarios where you can compel a landlord to transfer ownership (e.g. see my answer in relation to tenants under a lease of a flat in England & Wales). Ownership doesn't imply that you will always retain that ownership into perpetuity no matter what.

Comment: @JBentley, ok, so there may be cases where the outcome of a legal dispute is a judge forcing an owner out of the landlord business, (and maybe “silly” isn’t the right word) but the OPs statement “I think tenants own property” completely discredits all else in the question.  That’s the gap in understanding I’m trying to hone in on.